# Can we remove a root of a polynomial via multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Hypothesis: Let all operations, polynomials, and values defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime number. we assume all values and polynomials are non-zero.

---

*Case 1:* Let $F(x)=g(x)\cdot (x-\beta)$ where $\beta$ is an arbitrary element of the field.

**Question** 1: Can we remove a root of $F(x)$ by just multiplying it by another polynomial? i.e. $T(x)=D(x)\cdot F(x)$, $T(\beta)\neq0$

---

*Case 2:* Let $\textbf{x}=[x_1,...x_{n}]$, where $x_i\neq x_j$. We know that if we set $D(x_i)=(x_i-\beta)^{-1}$.Then we can remove a root of $F(x)$ as follows:

(a) set $c_i=D(x_i)\cdot F(x_{i})$.

(b) interpolate a polynomial using $(x_i,c_i)$ pairs. The polynomial interpolated would not have $\beta$.

**Question** 2: Is there any other way to remove the root of $F(x)$ via multiplication when the polynomial is represented in the $x,y$-coordinate form?

Comment: A root cannot be removed, since $F(\beta)=0$ implies that $T(\beta)=D(\beta)\cdot F(\beta)=D(\beta)\cdot 0=0$ in $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: Multiplication of polynomials can only *increase* the set of roots.

Comment: No, simply because $0\cdot p = 0$ no matter what polynomial $p$ is

Comment: thanks for the comments! Just to double-check: there are no techniques, e.g. using a multiplicative inverse of polynomials or the polynomial root, to remove a polynomial root, is that right?

Comment: if F(x) = (x-1)(x-2), to remove (x-1), you need to divide by G(x)=x-1 provided that x is not equal to 1. There is no other way (I guess) for real roots to be "removed".

Comment: just a question, why cannot we set $D(x)=\frac{U(x)}{x-\beta}$ where $U(x)$ is a fixed polynomial. So $T(x)$ will be $T(x)=D(x)\cdot F(x)$?