# How can we remove a polynomial root via multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

My question is related to this: [Can we remove a root of a polynomial via multiplication?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402824/can-we-remove-a-root-of-a-polynomial-via-multiplication)

---

Let all operations and values defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime number. Also, all polynomials are defined over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. We assume all values and polynomials are non-zero.

Let $F(x)=G(x)\cdot (x-\beta)$ where $\beta$ is an arbitrary element of the field.

We want to remove a root of $F(x)$ via multiplication. We set $D(x)=\frac{S(x)}{x-\beta}$.

**Question**: Is still $\beta$ a root of $R(x)=D(x)\cdot F(x)$?

---

Note that $(x-\beta)$ does not divide $S(x)$.

---

Edit:

Can I prove the following corollary as follows: Let $\tau(x)$ and $\gamma(x)$ be two arbitrary non-constant polynomials of degree at most $d$ such that $\tau(x),\gamma(x)\in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Then, the product of the two polynomials does not cancel out the polynomials roots, so the  roots of $\alpha(x)=\tau(x)\cdot\gamma(x)$ include all roots of both $\tau(x)$ and $\gamma(x)$.

proof: Let $\gamma(x)=\prod\limits^{b}_{i=1
}(x-c_{i})\prod \limits^{d-b}_{j=1}(x-e_{j})$, where $1\leq b\leq d$. The only way to remove $b$ roots, e.g. $c_{i}$, from $\gamma(x)$ via polynomial multiplication is either to set $\tau(x)$ to $\frac{\sigma(x)}{\prod\limits^{b}_{i=1}(x-c_{i})}$ for any non-zero $\sigma(x)$, not divisible by the denominator. But, $\frac{\sigma(x)}{\prod\limits^{b}_{i=1}(x-c_{i})}$  is undefined in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Or, to set $\tau(x)$  to the multiplicative inverse of $\prod\limits^{b}_{i=1}(x-c_{i})$. Nonetheless, there is no non scallar polynomials  in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ that has a multiplicative inverse. Thus, the product of the two polynomials preserves all  roots of both.

Comment: Maybe.  Does $(x-\beta)$ divide $G(x)$ or $S(x)$?  If not, then, working in $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$, no, $\beta$ is not a root.  Note that $D(x)$ is *not* a polynomial, so this doesn't contradict the comments to the linked question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks for your comment-- Can you explain why $D(x)$ is not a polynomial?

Comment: Polynomials don't have denominators that include $x$.

Comment: If $D(x)$ is a polynomial then $S(x) = D(x)(x - \beta)$, contradicting the statement that $(x-\beta)$ does not divide $S(x)$.

Comment: I do not quite get the question, but a root can be multiple also in a polynomial over a finite field, so dividing by $x-\beta$ need not be sufficient to remove the root $\beta$ (This is how I understand the question). Why do you call the division by $x-\beta$ a "multiplication" ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I conclude that it does not remove the root.

Comment: @Peter by multiplication I meant this: $D(x)\cdot F(x)$

Comment: I have added the new text to the question. Could you please give your opinion?